# Reference to a protocol inside a class throughs the following error: Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Tags: swift, xcode, class, swift-protocols

This is my current situation:

```
class FirstViewController: UITableViewController {
   ...
}

protocol SharedFunctions {
   func createEvent(event: Event, text: String)
}

extension FirstViewController: SharedFunctions {
   createEvent(event: Event, text: String) {
       ...
   }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   var sharedFunctions = SharedFunctions? // < Xcode error...

   @IBAction func postChatMessageAction(_ sender: Any) {
       self.sharedFunctions.createEvent(event: event, text: "New Event")
   }
   ...
}
```

> Error: Expected member name or constructor call after type name

When I change my code as Xcode suggest the error is gone but I get a error on the createEvent function

```
var sharedFunctions = SharedFunctions?.self //Xcode suggestion is adding .self
```

Now I get a error on createEvent function

```
@IBAction func postChatMessageAction(_ sender: Any) {
   self.sharedFunctions.createEvent(event: event, text: "New Event") // < Xcode error...
}
```

> Error: Type 'SharedFunctions?' has no member 'createEvent'

I also tried the following with a error:

```
weak var delegate = SharedFunctions? // < Xcode error...
```

> Error: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'SharedFunctions?.Type'

What I'm trying to do is, from my SecondViewController class I want to trigger the function createEvent() that I have in my FirstViewController class.

Comment: Change `=` to `:` here `weak var delegate = SharedFunctions?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   //Need change here
   var sharedFunctions : SharedFunctions? // < Xcode error...

     @IBAction func postChatMessageAction(_ sender: Any) {
      self.sharedFunctions.createEvent(event: event, text: "New Event")
     }
   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SharedFunctions declaration syntax is wrong. It should be

```
weak var delegate: SharedFunctions?
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a `func` keyword missing in the `FirstViewController`'s extension. Try implementing `createEvent(event:text:)` function like this:

```
extension FirstViewController: SharedFunctions {
   func createEvent(event: Event, text: String) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Other than that, the declaration of `sharedFunctions` property in `SecondViewController` is wrong. Try the following:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   var sharedFunctions: SharedFunctions?

   @IBAction func postChatMessageAction(_ sender: Any) {
       self.sharedFunctions.createEvent(event: event, text: "New Event")
   }
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps.